# Cucumber: How to skip a single step and continue with the scenario (Java, JUnit)

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have a scenario with following structure:

```
Scenario Outline: Sections displayed on login
  Given Robert is at the home page
  When Robert logs in as "<role>"
  Then the "<section1>" should be displayed
  And the "<section2>" should be displayed

  Examples:
  | email         | section1       | section2  |
  | Administrator | Administration | Profile   |
  | External      | IGNORED        | Profile   |
```

As you can see, there is a parameter "IGNORED" in the second example.
In case I detect this keyword during runtime, I want the step, the keyword appeared in, to be skipped.

At the moment I use this:

```
@Then("the {string} should be displayed")
public void the_section_should_be_displayed(String sectionName) {
   if(sectionName.contentEquals("IGNORED"))
       return;

   // rest of code
}
```

Here the step will be set as PASSED if the IGNORED keyword is there.
**What I want instead, is that this single step is marked as SKIPPED and that the following steps are still executed** and the full test scenario is afterwards marked as PASSED or FAILED depending on the status of the other steps.

So my question is:

**Is there a way to manually set a Cucumber step to status SKIPPED without skipping the rest of the scenario?**

I am aware that I could simply create two scenarios, one for each role. But I currently have no choice. **I can not change anything within the feature file and need to solve this with code.** So please try to answer the question if you can.
I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding logic to your step definition, consider making a separate scenario that skips this step. I'm assuming there is a reason that "section1" is not relevant to the role of "External"? It would be considered good practice to capture that in a different scenario with a different name. Remember that a goal of the feature files is to describe the intended behaviour of your system; using 2 different scenarios here allows you to specify what the difference in behaviour is for different roles.

For example, as follows:

```
Scenario Outline: Admin section is visible to Admin
  Given Robert is at the home page
  When Robert logs in as Administrator
  Then the Administration section should be displayed
  And the Profile section should be displayed

Scenario Outline: Relevant sections are visible to External
  Given Robert is at the home page
  When Robert logs in as External
  Then the Profile section should be displayed
```

Alternatively, if you want to check that specific section are / are not displayed, you could do something like this, and use the step definition to check a sectio is / is not displayed based on the provided value:

```
Scenario Outline: Sections displayed on login
  Given Robert is at the home page
  When Robert logs in as "<role>"
  Then the admin section "<admin>" be displayed
  And the "<section2>" should be displayed

  Examples:
  | email         | admin       | section2  |
  | Administrator | should      | Profile   |
  | External      | should not  | Profile   |
```

(My example might not be correct Gherkin, but should give you an idea)

Comment: Hello Marit. Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate your effort. But as I wrote before, I have no choice. I cannot change the feature files. That's why I need to solve this problem on stepdefinition side.

Comment: `if(!sectionName.contentEquals("IGNORED")) { // do your check}` should work. (I won't comment on not being able to change the feature file, other than that sounds like a less than ideal work situation)